# Missing arrowhead in networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

For a process analysis I need to generate a flow chart. It worked out pretty well using networkX. However, I need to use arrowheads on each node that is pointing to the arrival node.

I searched other solved questions and tried to use the presented solution, but the arrowheads are not showing up.

Thank you for any help!

```
# libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Build a dataframe with your connections
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'from':['A', 'B', 'C','A','E','F','E','G','G','D','F'], 
'to':['D' , 'A', 'E','C','A','F','G','D','B','G','C']})

# Build your graph
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to')

# Spectral
#nx.draw_spectral(G, with_labels=True, node_size=1500, node_color="skyblue")
nx.draw(G, pos=nx.spectral_layout(G), with_labels=True, node_size=500, 
node_color="skyblue", arrowsize=20, arrowstyle='fancy')
plt.title("Precedence Chart")
```

This is the actual output I get from this:

[Actual output without arrowheads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcRyf.png)

[From the other question I tried the answers for, this is the way how the arrowheads should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9vHt.png)

I really hope anyone knows the solution as I tried to solve this over the last 10 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a DiGraph (directed graph):

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```